# Open a form after a given date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a `Google Script` to make automatic forms. I'd like to make it unaccessible before a given date but I can't find any way to do it. Even from the [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows `Form.setAcceptingResponses()`, which you can use to toggle your form on & off. Set up such a function as a time-based trigger.

But you'll need to workaround the fact that container-bound Form scripts cannot have time-based triggers. (See [Issue 3431](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3431), and star it to increase it's priority.)

As a simple work-around, create a stand-alone script with these functions in it, and specify the ID of your form:

```
/**
 * Specify the form to operate on
 */
var formId = '--form-id--';
var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

/**
 * Set this up as a time-based trigger to open your form at
 * a specific date & time.
 */
function startAcceptingResponses() {
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

/**
 * Set this up as a time-based trigger to close your form at
 * a specific date & time.
 */
function stopAcceptingResponses() {
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
}
```

Then use the "Resources" menu to add time-based triggers and set up notifications, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#TimeTriggers).

Finally, make sure you've set the form starting state by clicking <kbd>Accepting</kbd> or <kbd>Not Accepting</kbd>.

---

To use this from your form-creation script, you need to use a [TriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) to create the trigger.

For example:

```
 // Creates a trigger that will run at noon on
 // Jan 14, 2014 (+/- 15 min)
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("startAcceptingResponses")
   .timeBased()
   .atDate(2014,1,14)
   .atHour(12)
   .create();
```